# How can I maintain randomly generated values when setState is called? | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have developed a dice rolling app in Flutter. I am encountering an issue where when you turn the screen (mobile), resize the window (desktop), change the amount of dice, or toggle the *Combo Label,* the value in each die resets to a random value. I only want this to happen when the *Roll* button is pressed. Below is the code in the *die_row.dart* file:

```
class DieRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int amount;
  final int _min = 1;
  final int _max = 6;
  final List<Die> _dice = [];
  final List<int> _dieValues = [];
  final List<Die> _diceSorted = [];
  final List<int> _dieValuesSorted = [];

  DieRow({this.amount = 2}) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      _dice.add(Die(
        portionOfScreen: amount,
        value: 1 + Random().nextInt(6),
      ));
      _dieValues.add(_dice[i].value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _dice.length; i++) {
      _diceSorted.add(_dice[i]);
      _dieValuesSorted.add(_dice[i].value);
    }

    _diceSorted.sort();
    _dieValuesSorted.sort();

    print(_dieValues);
    print(_dieValuesSorted);
  }

  List<T> _rangeFrom<T>(List<T> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for (int i = fromIndex; i <= toIndex; i++) //
      result.add(list[i]);
    return result;
  }

  bool _isPair(List<Die> dice) {
    if (dice.length == 1) return false;
    for (int i = 1; i < dice.length; i++) //
      if (dice[i].value != dice[i - 1].value) //
        return false;
    return true;
  }

  bool _isStraight(List<Die> dice) {
    if (dice.length == 1) return false;
    for (int i = 1; i < _dice.length; i++) //
      if (dice[i].value != dice[i - 1].value + 1) //
        return false;
    return true;
  }

  bool _isFullHouse(List<Die> diceSorted) {
    if (getGameType() != GameType.poker) return false;
    return (_isPair(_rangeFrom<Die>(diceSorted, 0, 2)) &&
            _isPair(_rangeFrom<Die>(diceSorted, 3, 4))) ||
        (_isPair(_rangeFrom<Die>(diceSorted, 0, 1)) &&
            _isPair(_rangeFrom<Die>(diceSorted, 2, 4)));
  }

  bool _isFourOfAKind(List<Die> diceSorted) {
    if (getGameType() != GameType.poker) return false;
    return _isPair(_rangeFrom(diceSorted, 0, 3)) ||
        _isPair(_rangeFrom(diceSorted, 1, 4));
  }

  List<Die> getDice() => _dice;

  List<int> getDieValues() => _dieValues;

  int getLength() => _dice.length;

  Combination getCombination() {
    switch (getGameType()) {
      case GameType.boardGame:
        if (_isPair(_dice)) //
          return Combination.pair;
        break;
      case GameType.poker:
        if (_isPair(_dice)) //
          return Combination.pair;
        if (_isFullHouse(_diceSorted)) //
          return Combination.fullHouse;
        if (_isFourOfAKind(_diceSorted)) //
          return Combination.fourOfAKind;
        if (_isStraight(_dice)) //
          return Combination.straight;
        break;
      default:
        if (_isPair(_dice)) //
          return Combination.pair;
    }
    return Combination.common;
  }

  GameType getGameType() {
    switch (amount) {
      case 1:
        return GameType.boardGame;
      case 2:
        return GameType.boardGame;
      case 5:
        return GameType.poker;
      case 6:
        return GameType.lottery;
      default:
        return GameType.custom;
    }
  }

  int getMin() => _min;

  int getMax() => _max;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: _dice,
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the *die.dart* file, if that is helpful:

```
class Die extends StatelessWidget implements Comparable {
  final int portionOfScreen;
  final int value;

  Die({@required this.portionOfScreen, this.value = 1});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / portionOfScreen,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.25,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/die$value.png',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(Object other) {
    return other is Die && this.value < other.value
        ? -1
        : other is Die && this.value > other.value
            ? 1
            : 0;
  }
}
```

And I do get what is happening: `setState` is getting called when anything changes (especially those frickin spacers). I just want to know an alternative way I could implement this functionality of a dynamic amount of dice, all able to generate random values. But with the setup I have now, `setState` triggers the random value regeneration. Any help?

Also, I am aware that I poorly implemented the `isFullHouse` and `isFourOfAKind` methods, but just... I'll do that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widgets are rebuilt and recreated on reload. I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Create and use a state that is external from your widget.
2. If #1 doesn't help, there is a package that seems to be made for this. It's called [Native State](https://pub.dev/packages/native_state).

Comment: For more on this learn how State Management in Flutter works. Personally, I use `rxdart`'s `BehaviorSubject` for state, and retrieve state with the `get_it` package

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Only Random Number is not enough for Dice, Random Position, Random angle also very important here. BTW before throwing Dice You need to Keep Dice in a Corner. then give a place with random rotation. I did not care about the board design and color of the dice etc. etc.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class DiceChange extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DiceChange> createState() => _DiceChangeState();
}

class _DiceChangeState extends State<DiceChange> {
  List<int> Dice = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
  ];

  List<int> rotate = [
    15,
    20,
    25,
    30,
    40,
    45,
    60,
    65,
    85,
    95,
    105,
    115,
    125,
    135,
    145,
    165,
  ];

  bool isRotated = false;

  int index = 0;
  int index2 = 4;
  int index3 = 6;

  int dice1Index = 0;
  int dice2Index = 0;
  int dice3Index = 0;

  void rotateBox(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      dice3Index = math.Random().nextInt(Dice.length);
      dice2Index = math.Random().nextInt(Dice.length);
      dice1Index = math.Random().nextInt(Dice.length);
      index = math.Random().nextInt(rotate.length);
      index2 = math.Random().nextInt(rotate.length);
      index3 = math.Random().nextInt(rotate.length);
      isRotated = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.black54,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          rotateBox(context);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 350,
          width: 350,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: isRotated
                ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
                : MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: isRotated
                    ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
                    : MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(rotate[index] / 360),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${Dice[dice1Index]}',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(rotate[index2] / 360),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${Dice[dice2Index]}',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              RotationTransition(
                turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(rotate[index3] / 360),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${Dice[dice3Index]}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```